# Can I in general upgrade to one of the latest MacOS but not the most latest one?

Tags: macos, upgrade

For example, on one Macbook, I have Mavericks. If I consider the Catalina too new and might not be too stable yet, can I choose and upgrade to either Mojave or High Sierra?

(App store won't show search result for Mojave or High Sierra. I had to use a link and open in Google Chrome to get to either [Mojave](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-mojave/id1398502828?mt=12) or [High Sierra in the app store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-mojave/id1246284741?mt=12).)

The real question is, can I upgrade from one MacOS to another freely? That's because, if there are 7 versions that are commonly used by people (Mavericks, Yosemite, El Capitan, Sierra, High Sierra, Mojave, Catalina), then upgrading from one version to any one is "7 choose 2" and therefore there are 21 possibilities, and is that supported?

Comment: wait... that question is about how to "download"... my question is about "can I upgrade to such version" (from Mavericks to Mojave, jumping a few versions in particular)

Comment: Can you upgrade is an exercise in hardware compatibility and the two OS you choose. Yes you can upgrade if the requirements are satisfied, no if not. I would vote to close as too broad but sending people to the how to download link is useful.

Comment: After the edit - upgrade yes, easily. Downgrade depends on whether you want to clean install or transfer/migrate data, which is much harder.

Comment: actually, the answer I was looking for, is whether Apple does preventive steps, so that upgrade is possible from one version to another, and by how many versions. For example, if Apple only supports upgrade to 3 versions, then it may only let you upgrade from Mavericks to Sierra, and then one more time to Mojave

Comment: @bmike you said, "Can you upgrade is an exercise in hardware compatibility and the two OS you choose. Yes you can upgrade if the requirements are satisfied, no if not."  So it is an exercise left to the poor middle class and lower class users?

Comment: You just have to read the hardware requirements for the os you want to upgrade to.  Is that a problem?

Comment: I wouldn't think it has to be manual reading of hardware requirement, rather than the OS upgrade keeps a list of supported hardware and show a notice if the hardware isn't supported. So you mean, you have to find out what graphics card is in the machine, and see if Mojave supports it? Then what about the CPU, the RAM, the BIOS, the webcam, etc. If would seem strange the Mojave upgrade not able to tell one hardware that it needs is not there.

Comment: All you need to know about the requirements for Mojave can be read right here: https://support.apple.com/kb/SP777?locale=en_US

Comment: Ok, so in general it is supported. But that's not what I was trying to find out from the question. The question is really, can you upgrade from Mavericks to High Sierra, or from Yosemite to Mojave, all in one step, without any problem, provided that there is no hardware compatibility problem